# pyspark slower than pure python in n-grams

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new starter for spark.
I'm working on Chinese n-grams now, trying to practice and utilizing spark to speed up.

I'm running on single machine in local mode and there are 32GB ram in my machine.

But my spark program run 2 hours with 8 cores 16 threads and still running, pure python program just run 1 or 2 minutes.

Data is from mongodb and I try to parallelize my content.

Here is my code:

```
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '16g')
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", 'dcard')

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("dcard") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://192.168.2.12:27017/dcard.talk_posts") \
    .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://192.168.2.12:27017/dcard.talk_posts") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = my_spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
content = df.select('content')
content_rdd = content.rdd
paralle_data = sc.parallelize(content_rdd.collect()).cache()

def remove_url_and_punctuation(sentence):
    # remove url
    if 'http' in sentence:
        sentence = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', sentence, flags=re.MULTILINE)

    # remove punctuation
    text_list = re.split('\W+', sentence)
    return list(filter(None, text_list))

def one_to_three_grams(line):
    return (Counter(line), to_ngrams(line, 2), to_ngrams(line, 3))

def to_ngrams(unigrams, length):
    return Counter(zip(*[unigrams[i:] for i in range(length)]))

result = paralle_data.flatMap(lambda s: remove_url_and_punctuation(s['content'])).map(lambda line: one_to_three_grams(line)).reduce(lambda a, b: tuple(map(operator.add, a, b)))
```

Data format is here:

```
print(paralle_data.top(1))
[Row(content='\n聽說今年在屏東某地的潮X高中\n全國繁星第一 (110人)\n但只有46個人上國立\n難道這就是所謂有學校就讀的概念嗎?\n\n還有據說繁星進大學的 都蠻優秀的\n是這樣嗎？')]

remove_url_and_punctuation(paralle_data.top(1)[0]['content'])
['聽說今年在屏東某地的潮X高中',
 '全國繁星第一',
 '110人',
 '但只有46個人上國立',
 '難道這就是所謂有學校就讀的概念嗎',
 '還有據說繁星進大學的',
 '都蠻優秀的',
 '是這樣嗎']
```

result should be a tuple and (one_grams_counter, two_grams_counter, three_grams_counter)

Do I miss somethings important in spark?

Update1:

Taking shanmuga's advice. I update my code.

```
content_rdd = content.rdd
paralle_data = sc.parallelize(content_rdd.collect()).cache()
result = paralle_data.flatMap(lambda s: remove_url_and_punctuation(s['content'])).map(lambda line: one_to_three_grams(line)).reduce(lambda a, b: tuple(map(operator.add, a, b)))
```

to

```
content_rdd = content_rdd.repartition(16)

result = content_rdd.flatMap(lambda s: remove_url_and_punctuation(s['content'])).map(lambda line: one_to_three_grams(line)).reduce(lambda a, b: tuple(map(operator.add, a, b)))
```

And it run 3 hours and still running.

Update2:

Here is my data size and this just one tenth of my total data.
When fix the problem, I will apply this on my total data.
[image]

and pure python code.
[image]

spark running main UI screenshot.

### [image]

[image]

---

And running after 2.5 hours.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are running on single machine in local mode and you are assigning all the available memory to executor i.e 16 GB, right? This leaves driver application with no memory. Try removing `setSystemProperty('spark.executor.memory', '16g')` statement and see what happens..

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have 32GB Ram, maybe it's not this issue~?

Comment: `sc.parallelize(content_rdd.collect())` Why are collecting the rdd (bringing the rdd to driver memory) then creating a new rdd out of it. This is useless (not sure if this is causing the problem).

Comment: @shanmuga Yeah it's kind of weird. but if I just use content_rdd to do the MapReduce, only three threads are running. But after parallelize, all 16 threads are running.

Comment: @Jimlin By default spark runs an executor for each input partition. Check how many partitions are created `content_rdd`. If required use `content_rdd.repartition` to increase the number of partition to a higher number (16, as the max number of threads that can be executed simultaneously is 16)

Comment: @shanmuga `content_rdd.getNumPartitions()` is 3, after `content_rdd = content_rdd.repartition(16)` `getNumPartitions` become 16. But after run mapreduce it still run 3 hours and still running.

Comment: @Jimlin You said your **pure python program runs for 1 or 2 minutes**, what is the size of your data? Since spark program runs for more than 2 hours we need to investigate the bottleneck in spark. Can you check if all 16 executors are being used (can be seen in application master UI), and share the pure python program as well.

Comment: @shanmuga Thank you for your reply, and I update the question to provide more information about spark and pure python program.